# Is it legal to bring Magpul firearm accessories into Russia?

Tags: luggage, legal, russia, firearms

I would like to know if it is legal to bring firearm *accessories* into Russia. My point of entry would be Sheremetyevo International Airport (SVO).

I would be coming from USA/JFK via Aeroflot, and these items would theoretically be in my checkin luggage:

- MOE Magpul sling  https://www.magpul.com/products/ms3-sling-gen2
- MOE Magpul AK grip
  https://www.magpul.com/products/moe-ak-grip-ak47-ak74
- MOE Magpul AK stock https://www.magpul.com/products/moe-ak-stock

These would be brand new (never used), still sealed and all plastic.

Aeroflot does allow weapons and has [a policy outlined here](https://www.aeroflot.ru/us-en/information/airport/security) for them. But, technically, these are not weapons, just firearm/weapon accessories.

Is this legal?

** EDIT: [According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magpul_Industries)

> Magpul Industries Corporation is an American designer and manufacturer
>   of high-tech polymer and composite firearms accessories.

** EDIT: @origimbo's provided [a link to "Federal Customs Service" English website](http://eng.customs.ru/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1686&Itemid=1908), which mentions "the import or export of 'service and civilian weapon, its major parts, and ammunition to it'" is limited but ***not prohibited***.

Comment: I'm not qualified to make the distinction (I suspect only the Russian Federal Customs Service is), but it appears that there is a prohibition on the import or export of  "service and civilian weapon, its major parts, and ammunition to it". It's possible the grip or stock might be assessed as such. http://eng.customs.ru/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1686&Itemid=1908

Comment: @origimbo thanks for your insight. I went ahead and emailed "Federal Customs Service" for an answer. I don't think these would be considered "major parts", since they're non functional or non essential.

Comment: @origimbo after reading the link you provided, it is clear that import or export of "service and civilian weapon, its major parts and ammunition to it" is NOT prohibited, but, it is *limited*. Please re-read the information in your link. Russian websites can be confusing :)

Comment: Well, I didn't have any problems and was not checked. I did not declare anything. My brother in law was very happy with his gift.

Comment: You're playing with matches here, it's nice to know that you're alright.

Comment: @alamar Right? Thank you. The link origimbo provided is no longer working the same and the information is different. So I have no idea. I think I will ask an officer when I go back to Moscow soon.

Answer (score 4):

## The Customs Rules

The Russian Federal Customs Service has [a webpage detailing the items that are controlled and/or prohibited for importation in Russia](http://eng.customs.ru/folder/87086). In relation to weapons it states:

> ## Goods, prohibited or limited for transfer via the customs border of the Eurasian Economic Union
>
> (in accordance with the decision of Board of the Eurasian Economic Commission dated April 21, 2015 No 30 “On non-tariff regulation measures”)
>
> ### List of the goods for the personal usage, prohibited to import into the customs territory of the Eurasian Economic Union (hereinafter - the Union) and (or) export from the territory of the Union
>
> 1 - In case of transfer via the customs border by any means:
>
> [...]
>
> 1.2 - service and civilian weapon, its major parts, and ammunition to it, prohibited for import and(or) export (section 1.6 of the Decision)

and

> ### List of the goods for personal usage, limited to import to the territory of the Union and(or) export from this territory
>
> 4 - In case of transfer via the customs border by any means:
>
> [...]
>
> 4.3 - Service and civilian weapon, its major (constituent) parts, and ammunition to it (section 2.22 of the Decision, Attachment No 17)

The Decision detailing which weapons are prohibited and which are limited for importation [can be found here](http://www.eurasiancommission.org/en/act/trade/catr/nontariff/Pages/ediny_perechen.aspx). The relevant sections are: [section 1.6](http://www.eurasiancommission.org/ru/act/trade/catr/nontariff/Documents/ed_p_starie%20faili/1.6%20-%20guns.doc) and [section 2.22](http://www.eurasiancommission.org/ru/act/trade/catr/nontariff/Documents/ed_p_starie%20faili/2.22%20-%20orujie.doc). Both these documents are in Russian but they can easily be parsed via Google Translate.

### What Are Major Contituent Parts of Firearms?

Doing so reveals that section 1.6 relates mostly to automatic weapons, gas weapons, radioactive ammunition, explosive cartriges, butterfly knives, and all such items whose importation one would expect to be prohibited by common sense. Section 2.22 instead relates to sport and hunting weapons, both cold weapons and firearms. In section 2.22 one can find an explanation of what is meant by "its major (constituent) parts". These seem to mean:

> 14. The main (component) parts of pistols and sporting revolvers
> 15. The main (component) parts of pistols and service revolvers
> 16. Trunks of hunting and sport smooth-bore rifles and carbines
> 17. Trunks rifled hunting and sports rifles and carbines
> 18. Other main (component) parts of hunting and sport smooth-bore guns (bolt, drum, frame, receiver (block), forend, trigger mechanism and parts and accessories to it)
> 19. The main (component) parts of sports rifles , hunting carbines, rifles with a rifled barrel (barrel, bolt, drum, frame, receiver (block), forend, trigger mechanism and parts and accessories to it)

This list does not include stock, sling and grip. This means that, in principle, **you should be allowed to import these three items into Russia**. However, to be extra safe and since I am not a lawyer, you should probably go ahead and declare them at customs and have the officers check this for you.

Comment: I think that is excellent advice and how I was leaning. Nobody really checks you after arrival in Moscow. It's up to you to walk over and speak to an officer, they really don't even look at you. I think the firearm accessories are not considered "major parts" but I guess it depends on the opinion of the person you talk to. Thanks for this.

Comment: @AussieJoe Please do not assume that since nobody checks you are not obliged to declare controlled imports when crossing customs. Not declaring is basically considered smuggling.

Comment: @JoeErNanO I did not assume anything, simply stating facts here. Since these are "_limited_" goods (but not restricted or prohibited), I do not feel obligated to declare them. Red channel declarations are for commercial goods, exceeded food limits (5kg or more), or prohibited/restricted items. Since these are "limited" they do not meet the criteria for declaration. You just proved that in your answer, unless this is not accurate information.

Comment: @AussieJoe I'm quite certain both "limited" and "restricted" refer to the same category ("ограниченные к перемещению") because the English translation of the term is not standardized. It becomes quite clear once you open the Russian page of the [prohibited/restricted("limited") goods](http://customs.ru/fiz/tovary,-zapreshhennye-ili-ogranichennye-k-peremeshheniyu-cherez-tamozhennuyu-graniczu-evrazijskogo-ekonomicheskogo-soyuza) or take a look at some [articles](https://www.alta.ru/sfo_news/62660/) that explicitly state that you *do* need to declare weapons/ammo when crossing the border.

Comment: @AussieJoe I'm just saying: 1. It's never safe to assume anything when it comes to legal matters, 2. When in doubt: declare it.

Comment: @undercat these are not weapons/ammo and that is quite clear as well. It's plastic accessories, not even major parts. The answer that received the bounty here says it must be "major (constituent) parts". These are none of those things.